# Inserting multiple rows per subquery in mysql

Tags: mysql, nested, subquery

I would like to do an insert using a select and then insert multiple rows per return value from the sub query for example

```
INSERT INTO t1 (column1, column2, column3)
SELECT column1_value,5,10 FROM t2;
```

would insert 5 into column2 for each row and 10 into each row for column three. Is there anyway that I can pass multiple values here to get one row with 5 in column 2 and another row with 7 per record obtained from the select from t2?

Comment: explain the logic you need for mullple value ..show a proper data sample

Answer (score 2):

Use `UNION`

```
INSERT INTO t1 (column1, column2, column3)
SELECT column1_value, 5, 10 FROM t2
UNION ALL
SELECT column1_value, 5, 7 FROM t2
```

You could also join with a `UNION`

```
INSERT INTO t1 (column1, column2, column3)
SELECT t2.column1_value, 5, t3.column3_value
FROM t2
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 10 AS column3_value
            UNION
            SELECT 7 AS column3_value) AS t3
```

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of ways to insert "this or that". Barmar listed two examples, but there's also IF, IFNULL, NULLIF, and CASE:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html